# NoReverseMatch at /courses/detail/modules/create_content

Tags: django

I want to create a quiz app for my e learning project and when i tray to add a new quiz in the modules content is says "Reverse for 'new-quiz' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['courses/(?P<courses_id>[^/]+)/modules/(?P<modules_id>[^/]+)/quiz/newquiz\Z']"
here is my code in quiz models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from courses.models import Modules,Courses



class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=900)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=900)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Quizzes(models.Model):
    module=models.ForeignKey(Modules,related_name='Quizzes',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due = models.DateField()
    allowed_attempts = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    time_limit_mins = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Attempter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quizzes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Attempt(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quizzes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attempter = models.ForeignKey(Attempter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.attempter.user.username + ' - ' + self.answer.answer_text

class Completion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quizzes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Completion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quizzes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    #assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and for quiz view

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

from quiz.forms import NewQuizForm, NewQuestionForm
from quiz.models import Answer, Question, Quizzes, Attempter, Attempt,Completion
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from courses.models import Modules,Courses


# Create your views here.

def NewQuiz(request, courses_id, modules_id):
    user = request.user
    module = get_object_or_404(Modules, id=modules_id)
    new_quiz=None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        quiz_form = NewQuizForm(request.POST)
        if quiz_form.is_valid():
            new_quiz=quiz_form.save(commit=False)
            new_quiz.module = module
            new_quiz.save()
            return redirect('new-question', courses_id=courses_id, modules_id=modules_id, new_quiz_id=new_quiz.id)
    else:
        quiz_form = NewQuizForm()

    context = {
        'quiz_form': quiz_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz/newquiz.html', context)


def NewQuestion(request, course_ids, module_ids, new_quiz_id):
    user = request.user
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quizzes, id=new_quiz_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewQuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            question_text = form.cleaned_data.get('question_text')
            points = form.cleaned_data.get('points')
            answer_text = request.POST.getlist('answer_text')
            is_correct = request.POST.getlist('is_correct')

            question = Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, user=user, points=points)

            for a, c in zip(answer_text, is_correct):
                answer = Answer.objects.create(answer_text=a, is_correct=c, user=user)
                question.answers.add(answer)
                question.save()
                quiz.questions.add(question)
                quiz.save()
            return redirect('new-question', courses_id=courses_id, modules_id=modules_id, new_quiz_id=new_quiz_id)
    else:
        form = NewQuestionForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz/newquestion.html', context)


def QuizDetail(request, courses_id, modules_id, new_quiz_id):
    user = request.user
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quizzes, id=quiz_id)
    my_attempts = Attempter.objects.filter(quiz=quiz, user=user)

    context = {
        'quiz': quiz,
        'my_attempts': my_attempts,
        'courses_id': courses_id,
        'modules_id': modules_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz/quizdetail.html', context)

def TakeQuiz(request, courses_id, modules_id, new_quiz_id):
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quizzes, id=new_quiz_id)
    context = {
        'quiz': quiz,
        'courses_id': courses_id,
        'modules_id': modules_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz/takequiz.html', context)

def QuizDetail(request, courses_id, modules_id, new_quiz_id):
    user = request.user
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quizzes, id=new_quiz_id)
    my_attempts = Attempter.objects.filter(quiz=quiz, user=user)

    context = {
        'quiz': quiz,
        'my_attempts': my_attempts,
        'courses_id': course_id,
        'modules_id': module_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz/quizdetail.html', context)


def SubmitAttempt(request, courses_id, modules_id, new_quiz_id):
    user = request.user
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quizzes, id=new_quiz_id)
    earned_points = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        questions = request.POST.getlist('question')
        answers = request.POST.getlist('answer')
        attempter = Attempter.objects.create(user=user, quiz=quiz, score=0)

        for q, a in zip(questions, answers):
            question = Question.objects.get(id=q)
            answer = Answer.objects.get(id=a)
            Attempt.objects.create(quiz=quiz, attempter=attempter, question=question, answer=answer)
            Completion.objects.create(user=user, courses_id=courses_id, quiz=quiz)
            if answer.is_correct == True:
                earned_points += question.points
                attempter.score += earned_points
                attempter.save()
        return redirect('index')


def AttemptDetail(request, courses_id, modules_id, new_quiz_id, attempt_id):
    user = request.user
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quizzes, id=new_quiz_id)
    attempts = Attempt.objects.filter(quiz=quiz, attempter__user=user)

    context = {
        'quiz': quiz,
        'attempts': attempts,
        'courses_id': courses_id,
        'modules_id': modules_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz/attemptdetail.html', context)
```

quiz.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from quiz.views import NewQuiz, NewQuestion, QuizDetail, TakeQuiz, SubmitAttempt, AttemptDetail

app_name ='quiz'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/newquiz', NewQuiz, name='new-quiz'),
    path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/<new_quiz_id>/newquestion', NewQuestion, name='new-question'),
    path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/<new_quiz_id>/', QuizDetail, name='quiz-detail'),
    path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/<new_quiz_id>/take', TakeQuiz, name='take-quiz'),
    path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/<new_quiz_id>/take/submit', SubmitAttempt, name='submit-quiz'),
    path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/<new_quiz_id>/<attempt_id>/results', AttemptDetail, name='attempt-detail'),

]
```

and in the for adding quiz template

```
 <div class="card pt-3 pb-3 text-center">
    <a href="{% url 'quiz:new-quiz' courses.id modules.id %}"> Create Exam </a>
  </div>
```

and for adding content

```
 <a href="{% url 'courses:create_content'  %}" class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3 mb-3">Add Content</a>
```

in courses url.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import *

app_name = 'courses'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CourseListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', CourseDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('create/', create_course, name="create"),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/create_module/', create_module, name="create_module"),
    path('detail/modules/create_content', create_content, name="create_content")
]
any one who can help me please ??
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that your urls are interfering with each other.

```
path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/newquiz', NewQuiz, name='new-quiz')
path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/<new_quiz_id>/', QuizDetail, name='quiz-detail'),
```

try changing it for:

```
path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/newquiz/', NewQuiz, name='new-quiz')
path('<courses_id>/modules/<modules_id>/quiz/<new_quiz_id>/detail/', QuizDetail, name='quiz-detail')
```

Also you should always finish the path with a '/'.
[More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: still the problem is here